# xCode 6: scene using MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate not working after first test - crashes iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm totally frustrated with this. I have a scene which reports on contents previously stored in Core Data. It was working and preparing the contents to be emailed. Suddenly it stopped working properly and the Fetch request returned an empty result state. I spent many hours on the Simulator without success. Then I decided to test it on my iPhone and it worked. I was very happy until I decided to test it again and it crashed my iPhone. When I attempted to test it again it did not return any data. However other scenes that fetch and store data using essentially the same code are working. I restored an earlier version of the script and it behaves the same way on the simulator (I did not test it on the iPhone.)

The only differences between the two screens is that the one that is not working uses a ScrollView and has this interface:  @interface CREWEmail : UIViewController

I tested it on the previous scene (without the scrollview) and it still does not return the results. It looks like the problem may be due to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Can anyone suggest what could cause this strange behaviour and how I can fix it?

I've included the relevant portion of the script below:

```
- (void) processAllViewNotes {

CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"View" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

// Execute Fetch Request

NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray * objects = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError]; // was * objects

NSLog(@"Objects ===> %@",objects);//    NSLog(@" objects count %lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]); // zero ... why?

if (fetchError) {
    NSLog  (@"getNotes Fetch error:%@", fetchError); // not displaying so no error?
};

NSString *viewName;
NSString * viewDescription;

if (! [objects count] == 0) {
//        NSLog(@" viewName %@", viewName);
    int i;
    NSManagedObjectContext * matches = nil;
    NSLog(@" objects count %lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);
    for (i=0; i < [objects count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@" i %i",i);
        matches = objects [i];
//          NSLog(@"matches %@",matches);

        viewName = [matches valueForKey : @"viewName"];

        viewDescription = [matches valueForKey : @"viewDescription"];

        NSString *viewNotes = [self processNotes:viewName];

        self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",self.textView.text,viewDescription,viewNotes]; // add view name and notes to text view

        // get matching switches (if any)
        NSString *switchText = [self processSwitches:viewName];

        self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\n", self.textView.text,switchText];
        } // end for
    } // end if count not zero
else { // count = 0
//        self.textView.text = @"no notes yet";
}
}
```

Comment: If it crash, what's the error message?

Comment: It crashed the iPhone once and when I look in the log it is completely empty. Does iOS8 clear the log after a crash? I know that there used to be many messages when I used it in earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: I also checked the OSX console and there are no xCode messages at the same time as the fetch failed.

Comment: I also just noticed that I had the wrong interface above. It is  @interface CREWEmail : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

Comment: Problem appears to be due to corrupted CoreData. I'm not sure what corrupted it but when I reset the contents (which I thought I had done before) the results were correct.